# Getting error sending Post data to server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am sending the data to server through api. But i am getting the error at response time.

Below is my code

```
 fetch('http://35.196.195.208/SaveRecommendAppDetails', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {              
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 },
        body: JSON.stringify({
                  UserId:"23",
                  ClientId:"2",
                  Name: "Paras", 
                  Email: "Paras@gmail.com", 
                  Phone: "9876543210",
                  CreatedUserId:"23" ,
                  Company: "Brill Infosystem"})
      })
      .then((response) =>JSON.stringify(response.json())) 
      .then((responseJson) =>{console.log( "==========response=========" + responseJson) })    
      .catch((err) => { console.log("==========error=========" + err); });
    }
```

And error is :
{ "_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ "_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null }` is what you get when you `console.log` a `Promise` object. The `response.json()` returns a `Promise`, so you can't just `JSON.stringify()` it. Remove the call to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: yeah, he's right and makes sure the field in your db/server are strings when you pass the numbers in string format.